# Itunes Connect "this build is invalid"

Tags: ios, admob, app-store-connect

Im including admob advertising in my app. For some reason when I include the GoogleAdMob framework in my project the build fails to upload to iTunes Connect. (The Google admob framework did not come with Xcode, it was downloaded from the Google admob website)

[image]

Comment: How do you know it's the framework? Have you uploaded a build without it?

Comment: yes and everything was fine

Comment: Need more information. Did you used Application loader or XCode organizer ? Most importantly did you got `A green tick mark` saying app uploaded successfuly ?

Comment: I archived the project normally and submitted it with whatever xcode came with. Everything was fine, except i couldn't select the build in itunes connect  because it was read only and said "the build is invalid"

Comment: do you know what the issue could be by any chance?

Comment: It probably points you in the right direction, that the build is invalid. So: when you build the app so you may send it to Apple, you should take the archive that was created and run it. You'll probably see some error there. This is not a complete answer, just hope this helps in dissecting the problem.

Comment: i got an email saying "There's an issue with the app's bitcode compilation. Rebuild the app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and upload it again." so im updating my xcode right now, but im still not sure if thats the issue or not but ill keep you posted, thanks